# Bootstrap table - row styling not applying on whole row?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap table and making table dynamically using haml. The problem I am facing is that for every `medication`, it can have a different number of `dosages`. So when a table is generated it do not have a uniform look. Styling of row having lesser number of columns do not cover full row. The reason behind is that `<td>` html code is not present in the DOM. I am looking for a bootstrap element or class which can analyze size of row dynamically considering largest row and apply bootstrap styling accordingly.

```
.table-responsive.table-bordered
  %table.table.table-striped
    %thead
      %tr
        %th Drug
        %th Dosage
    %tbody
      - user.medications.each do |med|
        %tr
          %th
            = med.drug.name
          -med.dosages.each do |dose|
            %td
              = dose.dosage_time
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, I came up with a solution to create empty columns in un-occupied row space. I calculated max row size and generated (max - current_size) number of columns. So that row should always of maximum size and styling etc apply to the whole row of table.

```
-max_count = max_dosage(user)
.table-responsive.table-bordered
  %table.table.table-striped
    %thead
      %tr
        %th Drug
        %th Dosage
    %tbody
      - user.medications.each do |med|
        %tr
          %th
            = med.drug.name
          -dosage_count = med.dosages.size
          -med.dosages.each do |dose|
            %td
              = dose.dosage_time
            -(max_count - dosage_count).times do 
              %td
```

Is there any other/better way to fix this issue?